# Page scrolls back to top when the menu panel is opened in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, panel

I've checked the jQuery mobile API documents and GitHub Issues but I can't find the answer to my question.

I've created a web app with the latest version of jQuery Mobile. The menu is a side panel that is opened when a link in the header is clicked. The header is fixed on top of the page.

In Safari & Chrome on iOS 7, when I scroll down the page and then open the side panel to get the menu, the page scrolls back to the top.

Is there any way to have the panel open without having the page scroll back to the top?

Thank you very much for your help!

Here is the code I use :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>Sentinelle</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="_assets/js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>(function(a,b,c){if(c in b&&b[c]){var d,e=a.location,f=/^(a|html)$/i;a.addEventListener("click",function(a){d=a.target;while(!f.test(d.nodeName))d=d.parentNode;"href"in d&&(d.href.indexOf("http")||~d.href.indexOf(e.host))&&(a.preventDefault(),e.href=d.href)},!1)}})(document,window.navigator,"standalone")</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos jqm-home">
    <div data-role="header" class="jqm-header"  data-position="fixed">
        <h2><img src="_assets/img/jquery-logo.png" alt="Logo"></h2>
        <a href="#" class="jqm-navmenu-link ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-icon-bars ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-btn-left">Menu</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="panel" class="jqm-navmenu-panel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a">
          <ul class="jqm-list ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon">
            <li data-filtertext="accueil" data-icon="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="questionnaire" data-icon="bullets"><a href="questionnaire.html" data-ajax="false">1</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="historique" data-icon="clock"><a href="historique.html" data-ajax="false">2</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="rapport" data-icon="mail"><a href="rapport.html" data-ajax="false">3</a></li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" data-iconpos="right" data-inset="false">
              <h3>4</h3>
              <ul>
                <li data-filtertext="about sentinel" data-icon="info"><a href="about_sentinel.html" data-ajax="false">5a</a></li>
                <li data-filtertext="about sentient" data-icon="info"><a href="about_sentient.html" data-ajax="false">5b</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li data-filtertext="conditions" data-icon="alert"><a href="conditions.html" data-ajax="false">6</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="conditions" data-icon="edit"><a href="mailto:contact@example.com" data-ajax="false">7</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="conditions" data-icon="comment"><a href="AppStore" data-ajax="false">8</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
        <!-- /panel -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content">
        <h1>Lorem</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" class="jqm-footer">
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Under</p>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution for futur googlers :

The link to open the panel should be :

```
<a href="#mypanel" class="jqm-navmenu-link ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-icon-bars ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-btn-left">Menu</a>
```

With the div for the panel set as :

```
<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" class="jqm-navmenu-panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" style="overflow:scroll; position: fixed;" data-animate="true">
```

See http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#option-positionFixed

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a href="#" class="jqm-navmenu-link ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-icon-bars             ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-btn-left">Menu</a>
```

The a href ="#" Will always go to top, you will have to change this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, changing the href to "#mypanel" and giving an id="mypanel" to the div of the panel stills makes the page scroll to the top.