# How to use Snap.js panels with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, snap.js

Does anybody know how to set up [Snap.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/tree/v2.0) in jQuery Mobile? I'm trying to migrate from the jQuery Mobile panel widget which has major scroll issues.

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/vZBzD/3/

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <a id="open-panel">Open panel</a>
        <div class="snap-drawers">
            <div class="snap-drawer snap-drawer-left">
                <ul>
                    <li>Pretty row 1</li>
                    <li>Pretty row 2</li>
                    <li>...</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div data-role="content" id="content" class="snap-content">
        <ul>
            <li>Pretty row 1</li>
            <li>Pretty row 2</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function () {
    var snapper = new Snap({
        element: document.getElementById('content')
    });

    if (document.getElementById('open-panel')) {
        addEvent(document.getElementById('open-panel'), 'click', function () {
            snapper.open('left');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Apart from my answer below, implemented in codepen, i have also forked your fiddle & updated it to make it work with the required changes - http://jsfiddle.net/nitishdhar/vZBzD/7/ . Note that jsfiddle might not be able to trigger the pagecontainershow event, so I have removed it.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672236/jquery-mobile-panel-open-scrolls-page-to-the-top-how-to-change-this/22675170#22675170 is a CSS fix for jQM panel scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per snap js, you don't need to place the snap js html content inside the jQuery mobile page content html.

You can break the page in two parts cleanly, the snap nav section & the actual jQuery mobile html structure.

**Working Demo**

http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/pIJkr

I have used jQuery + jQuery Mobile 1.4.2(JS) + jQuery Mobile 1.4.2(CSS) + Snap JS + Snap CSS as resources in the codepen, you can check them in specific JS & CSS sections settings button.

**Code Structure - Different Menu on Both Sides**

```
<body>
<!-- Snap Js Code Comes Here -->
    <div class="snap-drawers">
        <div class="snap-drawer snap-drawer-left">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="default.html">Default</a></li>
                    <li><a href="noDrag.html">No Drag</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dragElement.html">Drag Element</a></li>
                    <li><a href="rightDisabled.html">Right Disabled</a></li>
                    <li><a href="hyperextend.html">Hyperextension Disabled</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="snap-drawer snap-drawer-right">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="default.html">Default</a></li>
                <li><a href="noDrag.html">No Drag</a></li>
                <li><a href="dragElement.html">Drag Element</a></li>
                <li><a href="rightDisabled.html">Right Disabled</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Snap Js Code Ends Here -->

<!-- Jquery Mobile Code Comes Here -->
    <div data-role="page" id="content">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h4>&copy; Test App</h4>
        </div>
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            Some Page Content
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h4>&copy; Test App</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now apply some CSS as per your requirement of design, but you might need the z-index -

```
#content {
    background: #BFC7D8;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Now initiate the snap nav -

```
var snapper = new Snap({
    element: document.getElementById('content')
});
```

This should work fine now.

**Alternate Example with same Menu on both sides**

Also, if you want to show the same menu on both sides, just remove the menu items from the snap-drawer-right div & only keep menu items in the left one like this -

```
<div class="snap-drawer snap-drawer-left">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="default.html">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="noDrag.html">No Drag</a></li>
            <li><a href="dragElement.html">Drag Element</a></li>
            <li><a href="rightDisabled.html">Right Disabled</a></li>
            <li><a href="hyperextend.html">Hyperextension Disabled</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="snap-drawer snap-drawer-right"></div>
```

Now Add this to your CSS -

```
/* Show "Left" drawer for the "Right" drawer in the demo */
.snapjs-right .snap-drawer-left {
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}

/* Hide the actual "Right" drawer in the demo */
.snapjs-right .snap-drawer-right {
    display: none;
}
```

Working Demo - http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/LliBa

Comment: Thanks a bunch !! Wish I could mark both y'all answers as correct, but @Gajotres was first so :(

Comment: thanks. glad I could be of help. I saw that javascript error but then I saw your implementation was wrong. So thought would go ahead and create one the right way. As you can see in @Gajotres fiddle, your nav is not visible on reveal and your header button stays on top of the opened panel as compared to my output where you see the whole page slide left & right as expected.

Comment: Awesome :) Made yours the correct btw. Thanks again.

Comment: @MarkBoulder - I have added the same menu on both sides example in my answer.

Comment: Was just about to create a separate q. I really appreciate it. If you ever need help with design or branding or anything like that you let me know! bless :)

Comment: @MarkBoulder - Sure thing. thanks :) Also, it wouldn't be right to create a new post for a very similar question, so you were right first in asking the same in you comment. take care

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54472/discussion-between-mark-boulder-and-nitish-dhar).

Comment: Greetings! Been a long time - I hope you are doing fine. I just discovered a bug - seems our solution will not work across multiple jQuery Mobile pages: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/phpyf0ws/5/ - might you be able to offer any clues?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what's the problem? You had a JavaScript error with click event binding, I just changed it to jQuery like binding.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/as8P4/

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function () {
    var snapper = new Snap({
        element: document.getElementById('content')
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#open-panel',function () {
        snapper.open('left');
    });
});
```